# Insert JSON Data into relational Table in MYSql in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a table named tbleventbyminutes with the following structure in MYSql version 8.0

```
CREATE TABLE `tbleventbyminutes` (
  `eventbyminuteid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `matchid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `minute` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `halftime` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `createddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `userid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventbyminuteid`)
);
```

Now I have an Excel file where these data has been stored in a Excel sheet.

To insert the data into the table I have used

```
INSERT INTO `tbleventbyminutes` (`matchid`, `minute`, `halftime`, `value`, `createddate`, `userid`)
select 10001,1,1,'A',DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(),'%Y-%m-%d'),1 union all
select 10001,1,1,'A',DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(),'%Y-%m-%d'),1 union all
select 10001,1,1,'R',DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(),'%Y-%m-%d'),1 union all
select 10001,1,1,'B',DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(),'%Y-%m-%d'),1 union all
select 10001,1,1,'X',DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(),'%Y-%m-%d'),1 union all
select 10001,1,1,'4',DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(),'%Y-%m-%d'),1 union all
select 10001,1,1,'X',DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(),'%Y-%m-%d'),1
```

After running this script the data is been successfully inserted into the table
Now while parsing the Excel file these data came to my procedure into the form of JSON Data like

```
[
  [
    "select 10001",
    "1",
    "1",
    "'A'",
    "DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(),'%Y-%m-%d')",
    "1",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    "select 10001",
    "1",
    "1",
    "'A'",
    "DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(), '%Y-%m-%d')",
    "1",
    "0"
  ]
].....
```

Now my problem is how can I make or prepare the above mentioned select statement from this JSON data so that the data can be stored in the table. After inserting the data in this table I have to calculate some formula based on the "Value" field in the table.

Any help to prepare the Select statement or Insert the data into the table is appreciated. 
If for this any change in the JSON structure is needed then this can also be done.

Parsing is done in the Angular and the JSON is passed through a .Net api and a PL/SQL procedure having an in variable @jsonData is being called through the .Net API

In the JSON viewer the JSON structure is shown like this
[image]

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I may have took a wrong path.
For this instance problem I have took a different approach like this and this solves the issue.

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE `tbleventbyminutes` (
  `matchid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `minute` int DEFAULT NULL
);
-- insert some value
INSERT INTO tbleventbyminutes (matchid,minute)
SELECT *
     FROM
      JSON_TABLE(
        '{
    "action": "SaveEventByMinutes",
    "eventbyminutes": [
        {
            "matchid": "10001",
            "minute": "1"
        },
        {
            "matchid": "10001",
            "minute": "2"
        },
        {
            "matchid": "10001",
            "minute": "2"
        }
    ]
}',
         "$.eventbyminutes[*]"
        COLUMNS(
           matchid VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.matchid" DEFAULT 'null' ON EMPTY DEFAULT '999' ON ERROR,
           minute VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.minute" DEFAULT 'null' ON EMPTY DEFAULT '999' ON ERROR
     )
    ) AS tt;

-- fetch some values
SELECT * FROM tbleventbyminutes;
```